# Google play games - which SHA1 should I put in while creating client id

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api, sha1, google-play-games

I published a game on play store (without games services). 
With a SHA1 cert starting **c8:38:66** 
Now I want to add google play games services.

I have changed my eclipse since then. thus now I Have a different SHA1 eclipse which is like **DC:17:FD.**

When I go to create a client id in google play developer console it asks for SHA1 certificate.
**Which SHA1 should I enter there.**

NOTE : **I have the KEYSTORE for the published app** SHA1-c8:38:66.
And if your ANS is the published SHA1 i.e c8:38:66 .
then how do I run it on Emulator (I am using genymotion)?

Comment: Don't use CAPS like this it makes the question very hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add **BOTH** SHA1 entries if you want to use it for testing as well as for the published app.

You can link up to 20 apps to each game service - where in this case each signing key (publish+debug) will be one "app".

In the future, if the debug key changes then you can simply add the new debug key's SHA1.

Comment: How do I declare an SHA1 as a **DEBUG SHA1** . I mean their is No Such Option. Or Should i jusst Add it Like a Normal SHA1. @free3dom

Comment: Just add it the same as your release SHA1.

Comment: Thank you SO much. It was Indeed helpfull.